# Is $\operatorname{dom}(A^*A)$ a core of $A$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

By this I mean: Given $x\in\operatorname{dom}(A)$, does there exist a sequence $(x_n)\subset\operatorname{dom}(A^*A)$ such that $x_n\to x$ and $Ax_n\to Ax$?

Here, $A$ is a closed and densely defined linear operator in a Hilbert space.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. Found the proof in the book by Kato (Theorem V.3.24).

Comment: Page 275 (for those of us who struggle with Kato's theorem numbering scheme).

Comment: I agree. I find his numbering pretty confusing.